# D3 sliding focus and context

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I viewed this tutorial http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367, with focus and context using brush. I have a similar need, but I need to allow users to swipe left and right to view different context rather than using the brush at the bottom.

[image]

**My Questions:**

1. If i have data for Jan1-Dec31 2016. Do I have to manually break apart the data by weeks or can I control or set a default 7 days to show in the view and some how change the context on the same year long data set.
2. If I can set a default 7 days in the view, how can I allow a user to swipe left to move the graph up the time line, and swipe right to move backwards in time until reaching the end?

**What I've done**

1. I'm new to data visualization, SVG, and d3 so i read [Interactive Data Visualization](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449339735).
2. Created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ouqvou2L/) with the data manually filtered into a seven day window [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ouqvou2L/), with two graphs, both having the scale against time. I need to change the time scale for both graphs as users swipe.

**Data Format**

```
{
   date: '2016-08-01',
   kWh: 0.178,
   temp: 78
}
```

---

**Main code**

```
var width = 500,
    height = 600,
    margin = {top:20, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 10};
var mainSvg = d3.select('#svg-bars')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)

var midLine = mainSvg.append('line')
    .attr('x1', 250)
    .attr('y1', 0)
    .attr('x2', 250)
    .attr('y2', 600)
    .attr('stroke-width', 2)
    .attr('stroke', '#48BDC3')
    .attr('stroke-dasharray', 3);

var orgData = getData();


createTempChart();
createUsageChart();

/////////////////////////////////



function createTempChart() {
    var width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // Setup Scales
    var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain([getDate(orgData[0]), getDate(orgData[orgData.length - 1])])
        .range([0, width]);
    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([d3.min(orgData,domainTemp), d3.max(orgData, domainTemp)])
        .range([height, 0]);
    // Setup x-Axis
    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
        .tickArguments([3])
        .tickSize(0);

    var lineFunction = d3.line()
        .x(function (d) {return xScale(getDate(d))})
        .y(function (d) {return yScale(getTemp(d))})
        .curve(d3.curveCardinal);

    var weatherChart = mainSvg
        .append('g')
        .attr('class','weather-chart')
        .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

    weatherChart.selectAll('circle')
        .data(orgData)
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', function (d) {return xScale(getDate(d));})
        .attr('cy', function (d) {return yScale(getTemp(d));})
        .attr('r', 5);

    weatherChart.append('path')
        .attr('d', lineFunction(orgData))
        .attr('stroke', 'blue')
        .attr('stroke-width', 2)
        .attr('fill', 'none');

    weatherChart.append('g')
        .attr('class','y-axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',0)')
        .call(yAxis);
}

function createUsageChart() {

    var width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
            .domain([getDate(orgData[0]), getDate(orgData[orgData.length-1])])
            .range([0, width]),
        yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(orgData, domainY)])
            .range([height,0]);

// Setup x-Axis
    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
    .tickArguments([7])
        .tickSize(0);
    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
        .tickArguments([2, ''])
        .tickSize(0);

    var lineFunction = d3.line()
        .x(function(d){return xScale(getDate(d))})
        .y(function(d){return yScale(d.kWh)})
        .curve(d3.curveCardinal);


    var svg = mainSvg
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,300)')
        .attr('class','usage-chart')
        .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

    svg.selectAll('circle')
        .data(orgData)
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', function (d) {
            return xScale(getDate(d));
        })
        .attr('cy', function (d) {
            return yScale(d.kWh);
        })
        .attr('r', 5);

    svg.append('path')
        .attr('d', lineFunction(orgData));

    svg.append('g')
        .attr('class','y-axis')zq
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'y-axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',0)')
        .call(yAxis);

}


function getData(){
    return [{"date":"2016-08-01T00:00:00-05:00","kWh":0.43590624999999994,"temp":89},{"date":"2016-08-02T00:00:00-05:00","kWh":0.3778749999999999,"temp":81},{"date":"2016-08-03T00:00:00-05:00","kWh":0.36741666666666667,"temp":78},{"date":"2016-08-04T00:00:00-05:00","kWh":0.3568229166666667,"temp":77},{"date":"2016-08-05T00:00:00-05:00","kWh":0.3960416666666667,"temp":73},{"date":"2016-08-06T00:00:00-05:00","kWh":0.3565833333333333,"temp":83},{"date":"2016-08-07T00:00:00-05:00","kWh":0.2819062500000001,"temp":71}];
    }

function domainX (datum){
    return getDate(datum.date);
}

function domainY (datum){
    return datum.kWh;
}

function domainTemp (datum){
    return datum.temp;
}


function getDate(d) {
    return new Date(d.date);
}

function getTemp(d) {
    return d.temp
}
function randomIntFromInterval(min,max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}
```